# How can i aggregate all element in one column to have a string by linq

Tags: linq

How can i aggregate all element in one column to have a string by linq

For example: 
  I have table named:Items And one column of table named: ListItem

```
                    ListItem
                      1
                      2
                      3
```

How can I select all elements in Column ListItem  to have string  :   123

(Not select each values of column and join together)

Tks for everyone's help !!!

Comment: -1 Very trivial question, a google search would have taken less time than typing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think all answers with string.Join are incomplete since this method needs **an array** of strings, not **an IEnumerable**.

This should work.

```
var data = ...
var result = string.Join(" ", data.Select(x => x.ListItem).ToArray());
```

This results in:

```
"1 2 3"
```

Comment: String.Join does not need an array anymore and accepts an IEnumerable, at least since .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using typed data as List and it has id as property. then to aggregate the ids into one string you can do like this.

```
string.Join(" ", listofEmployees.Select(e=>e.Id));
```

this will print like

```
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) to extract the values you need and combine them into a string with [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

```
var table = new DataTable("Items");
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LiItem", typeof(int)));
table.Rows.Add(1);
table.Rows.Add(2);
table.Rows.Add(3);

Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["LiItem"])));
```

Output:

> 123

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying "Aggregate", then you might be interested to know that this is an actual LINQ method:

```
var a = new[]{"1","2","3"};
var concatenated = a.Aggregate("",(t,s)=>t+s);
```